# How can I install windows fonts in gnome ubuntu, but only if they are not already installed

Tags: 14.10, fonts, gui

Before installing ubuntu I copied all my data which included the windows fonts. There were fonts added by me, fonts added by adobe software and so on...

I added a few by hand, but it is bloody tedious!

Ist there any program that can install all fonts from a folder if they aren't already installed? Preferably a GUI program?

Comment: What program installs them "by hand?" Can it be run from a  terminal? (While it's running, you could try a `ps ax|less` or `pgrep -l font` to maybe see the program that's running, if you have no clue about it what it's called. I don't have any windows font files to try)

Comment: If i double click on a font, a program opens and shows me the font, I can then click on the install button to install it to ubuntu gnome... I guess I have about 100 fonts or so from windows 8/ms office, and adobe apps and google fonts that I want to install but it takes to much time to double click each one and then click on install. I can't remember what the program is called, I shall have a look tonight after work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to these webpages ([1](http://blog.solancer.com/2011/10/batch-install-ttf-fonts-on-ubuntu.html), [2](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/installing-fonts-linux)), it should be as simple as copying the font files to a specific folder. Any one of these folders should work:

- `/usr/local/share/fonts/`
- `/usr/share/fonts/`
- `~/.fonts/` (for fonts visible only to the current user)

(And having the font files with read permissions for all may be required for other users to use them, either `chmod 644 (fontfiles)` or `chmod uga+r (fontfiles)`

Comment: What is the difference between the first two folders? Is there any difference in putting fonts in say, the second location, instead of the first? I think I would rather put them in one of the first two so that anyone who used my computer can access them too

Comment: On a single-user computer it probably wouldn't make a difference, I'm not 100% sure, but I think the `/usr/share/` folder is like the "main/original" one, while `/usr/local/share/` is if you want to edit files, but still keep the "originals" available.